# View with auto layout doesn't resize

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `static UITableViewCell` in a `containerView` with `auto layout` applied. In the `containerView` is a `UIView`. I set the border color of the `containerView` to orange, and the `view` to green. When I run it on the simulator I get the following results:

**Constraints:**

[image]

**Portrait:**

[image]

**Landscape:**

[image]

The green border color is applied to the outer `view`.

When the the `simulator` goes in landscape mode, the `views'` width doesn't become as small as it should be; as you can see the `views'` right green border is not shown. (I have the same issue with the second `UISegmentedControl`.) Can someone please explain why this happens and provide a solution?

**Edit**

When in portrait mode, the `containerView` (and another `view`) are 1 on top of another. When in landscape mode, they are side by side. That's why in landscape mode, the `containerView` is smaller.

Comment: The screenshot of the document outline shows the top-level constraints. What about constraints within "View", which is collapsed in that screenshot? If the view has internal constraints that "push out", that can prevent the view from getting smaller.

Comment: I updated the image to include the inner view with its' `constraint`. Also, If the inner `views` constraint pushes out the outer `view`, then (in this case,) it should push the outer view out on all 4 sides, not just the right side. But thanks for the pointer!!

Comment: I don't understand the second image. If it is landscape, it should by wider. Why isn't it?

Comment: Add Height and Width Constraint to your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirements

**first UISegmentedControl**
 [image]

**second UISegmentedControl**
[image]

Follow these links [Autolayout](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/) or [Autolayout programatically](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/)

This might helps you :)

Comment: @Jessica Thanks for appreciation